# How does INDEX work in a query with UNION ALL?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with identical structures. Both have an index on column `name`. My query looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name in ('a', 'long', 'list')
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE name in ('a', 'long', 'list')
```

I know if I just want `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name in ('a', 'long', 'list')` then an index on column `name` in `table` is the optimal one. I wonder is it also the case if I use `UNION ALL` or there is a better way to speed up the above query. Thanks

Comment: In UNION each subquery is executed separately and independntly. So create index for improving each separate subquery independently.

Comment: your long list  is obtained  from a query??  .. a IN clause is paratically execute  as several OR condition  ..  (a select for each OR )